# Use case for `&` ref-qualifier?

Tags: c++

I just discovered this is valid C++:

```cpp
struct S { 
  int f() &;         // !
  int g() const &;   // !!
}; 

int main() {
    S s;
    s.f();
    s.g();
}
```

IIUC, `this` is passed to `f` by reference and to `g` be passed by const-reference.

How was this useful to anyone?

Comment: @AndyG Thanks! How can I control which overload is called? And can you give an example why would I want that?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function

Comment: In addition to duplicate, note that `const` and `&` are completely separate in this case. `int g() const` would get you the same result (`this` would be `const S*`). However, you now cannot do `S{}.f();` or `S{}.g();`, both will be compiler errors.

Comment: I could see a hypothetical situation where I have some particularly destructive functions that should only be called on an r-value reference, and I want to prevent the user from calling them on an l-value ref.

Comment: The marked duplicate is about overloaded functions with reference qualifiers - and therefore not a duplicate - it is a (perhaps subtly) different use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are useful for both providing safety and optimizations.

For member functions returning a pointer to something they own (either directly or via view types like `std::string_view` or `std::span`), disabling the rvalue overloads can prevent errors:

```
struct foo {
    int* take_ptr_bad() { return &x; }
    int* take_ptr() & { return &x; }
    int x;
};

foo get_foo();

void bar() {
    auto ptr = get_foo().take_ptr_bad();
    // ptr is dangling
    auto ptr = get_foo().take_ptr();
    // does not compile
}
```

The other is to provide some optimizations. For instance, you might overload a getter function to return an rvalue reference if `this` is an rvalue to prevent unnecessary copies:

```
struct foo {
    const std::string& get_str() const & {
        return s;
    }
    
    std::string&& get_str() && {
        return std::move(s);
    }
    
    std::string s;
};

void sink(std::string);

foo get_foo();

void bar() {
    sink(get_foo().get_str()); 
    // moves the string only if the r-value overload is provided.
    // otherwise a copy has to be made, even though the foo object
    // and transitively the string is temporary.
}
```

These are how I use the feature, and I'm sure there are more use cases.